# google app invite - sms are not sent

Tags: firebase, google-app-invites, firebase-invites

I've tried searching for a solution with no luck yet. I am trying to use the google app invite to invite friends to use my app (android). Emails are sent but sms are not. I do not get any error message, in fact I actually get a message that the invitation has been sent. I also tried adding sms permission to my app..
Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey did u solve the issue. I am searching for the code to send invite via sms. If u have could please able to share the code?

Comment: Yes, I had a weird character in the message itself (was invisible to the eye) because I copied the text to be sent in the sms itself.
The code itself is the same as for the email:

Comment: private void onInviteClicked() {
        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invite_friends))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.invite_message))
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invite_url)))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940408/android-google-app-invite-sample-is-not-sending-email-and-message-what-i-am-doin Please help I am facing this issue

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here. To solve it **reduce the length of your message**.

As we know, the message must be not longer than 100 symbols. But this is true only for latin characters. If your message contains **at least one** non-latin symbol (it switches to UCS-2 encoding), then the maximum length becomes only 39 symbols long (have tested Russian only).

So if you're trying to submit 40+ symbols, the message won't be sent.

Comment: I created bug report to Firebase support. There is no answer yet. :(

Comment: As workaround for localized version I pass short message to `setMessage()` and full description to `setEmailHtml()`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Emails were sent, but SMS messages not (although the app showed a snackbar saying that the invitation was sent). Apparently SMS messages are not sent when the message text contains some "more special" characters. In my case the text contained a "ë". After removing this character, SMS messages were successfully sent.

Comment: yes, that indeed was my problem as well :) I wish you had responded back then, would have saved me a lot of time :)
Thanks for sharing!