# Android Google App Invite sample is not sending email and message,What i am doing wrong?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I am using Android Google App invite sample and following all guidelines but it is not sending any messages and emails, it gives message

> Message Failed to Send

and in logs i am getting

> onActivityResult: requestCode=0, resultCode=3`
>
> getInvitation:onResult:Status{statusCode=CANCELED, resolution=null}

Comment: Link to sample code?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites

Comment: this is the link of sample code that i am using  https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites

Comment: @childofthehorn do you have any idea dude

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is an issue with your client configuration file. Make sure you followed [Step 2: get a configuration file](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/start) in the App Invites guide and have added the the google-services.json file to your project.

Check that package_name and certificate_hash match your credentials in Developers Console for the Default Demo App. Note: the certificate_hash will not have the colon delimiters.

```
  // from: google-services.json
  ...
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "<id>",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.google.android.gms.samples.appinvite",
        "certificate_hash": "<Signing-certificate fingerprint>"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: I already added this configuration file, but still not working for me :(

Comment: Make sure the **certificate_hash** and **package_name** for oauth_client in your google-services.json matches the Credentials you have defined in the Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating dubug build. But when I change Build variants from debug to release the problem solved.