# Google app invite SMS not getting sent but email working fine

Tags: ios, sms, google-app-invites

i have implemented Google App Invite in iOS. Code :

```
self.inviteDialog = [GINInvite inviteDialog];
[self.inviteDialog setInviteDelegate: self];
NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message",
                     [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] currentUser].profile.name];
[self.inviteDialog setMessage: message];
[self.inviteDialog setTitle: @"App"];
[self.inviteDialog open];
```

I am able to send the email but SMS are not getting sent.

When i enter a phone number "MFMessageComposeViewController" opens with text :

"Message Link" but then SMS is not getting sent.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google app invite - sms are not sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713748/google-app-invite-sms-are-not-sent)

Answer (score 0):

SMS messages are not sent when the message text contains some "`more special`" characters.

Try to use less number of symbols.

Try to reduce Message length.